# Visual Studio Regex for converting method call to array index

Tags: regex, visual-studio, powershell

I'm doing some code refactoring (converting VB to c# although that shouldn't be relevant).

A convertor has given me code that looks like this.

```
variable("name")
```

What I need is

```
variable["name"]
```

The code is used in various places, so you get all these instances that I need to workaround.

```
someVariable = variable("name");
someVariable = variable("someOtherName").ToUpper();
someVariable = Convert.ToInt32(variable("ThisName"));
```

Essentially, all the normal code usages of a method, and I need them to changes to array references instead.

I will plugin the name of the "variable" into the regex, but the regex needs to ensure as little side effects as possible.

If possible, I would like the regex to be broken down into what it's actually doing as I'm trying to learn it too.

I also would like to run this through Visual Studio Find and replace tool if possible, but if not, it needs to be something in powershell.

Comment: will "name" be the same?

Comment: No, I'll amend the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this basic regex

```
Find: (variable)\((".+?")\)
Replace : $1[$2]
```

Explanation

```
(  
  variable  // capture the group to use in replace
)
\( // match literal (
(  
    ".+?" // match the string and capture it in a group
)
\) // match literal )
```